# Mysql WHERE IN subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I'd like to list all rows having a match on same table.
So far i have came up with this

```
SELECT *
FROM parim_firms
WHERE firm_name IN (
    SELECT firm_name
    FROM parim_firms
    GROUP BY firm_name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

But this query keeps running, although the subquery itself runs in 0.1 sec.

How could i optimize this?

I think the subquery executes for each row, not only once. Am i right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about joining it?

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    parim_firms a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT firm_name
            FROM parim_firms
            GROUP BY firm_name
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON a.firm_name = b.firm_name
```

*PS: be sure to add index on column `firm_name` for faster execution.*